# How to collect values from form dynamically

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to refresh a form (on the client side) when a different user (that are listed in a table) is selected.

From my Controller I am sending an object and I show the values of the first user and I want that when another user name is clicked  the form changes with his data.
I have access to all the data of the users (if I do some alerts gettig the values of the different users they are shown correctly) but I don't know how to refresh by jQuery the form.

When a user is clicked I remove all the rows from the table:

```
$('.list-us').click(function() {
  var rowId = this.id;
  var id = rowId.substring(4, rowId.length);
  $("#user-list").val(id);
  $('#body-tab > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
   });
  loadUserRegisters(id);
});
```

And I call to function loadUserRegisters(id) sending the id of the user which I want to show his data
The method -symplyfied- is:

```
function loadUserRegisters(id) {
  var register = "<tr class='input' id='register'>"
        + "<td><input value='${user[id].periods[period].registers[0]}' /></td></tr>";
  $('#body-tab').append(register);
}
```

The idea is to show the value of the field user[id].periods[period].registers[0] but 'id' is despised and 'period' that is a hidden input too.

Oherwise, if I do

```
alert('${user[1].periods[1].registers[0]}');
```

hardcoding the id and period, I have what I want.

I am doing something wrong, maybe I have to use id and period variables in other way like

```
'${user['+id+'].periods[period].registers[0]}'
```

... but I've tried everything and I don't find the way.

Thank you so much, I really need help

Comment: We can't see what actual id values on rows are or what data looks like. The only row id shown is a hard coded one `"register"`. Need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not evrything is hardcored, the value register is not: <input value='${user[id].periods[period].registers[0]}' />. What more information do you need?

Comment: We can't see what `var rowId = this.id;` returns since not html was provided

Comment: rowId is the word 'user' concatenate with increment id, for that I do a substring to get only the id value

Comment: Again, we can't help without a [mcve] that we can run to see your issue in browser

Comment: I realized that it is not possible to use value='${user[id].periods[period].registers[0]}' in jQuery because is in the client side, so my problem is how to call to an specific field depends on a variable in client side. I would like to collaborate more posting all the code but there is to much and I do not really know where to start from